# Rails association cannot be blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, associations

I'm building off the tutorial app in ruby on rails for a project, and I'm trying to create an association between two models.

In my database, there are users, events, and an attendance table that associates with the email from a user and a code from an event.

I've tried to research how to do this myself, but every time I try to validate the attendance email to a user, it states that the user cannot be blank as if I were trying to create a new one.

Still quite new to Ruby on Rails, so any advice would be appreciated! The models are below.

**User Model:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :name, :password, :password_confirmation
  has_secure_password

  has_many :attendances, inverse_of: :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :attendances

  before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }
  before_save :create_remember_token

  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates(:name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 })
  validates(:email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false})
  validates(:password, length: { minimum: 6 } )
  validates(:password_confirmation, presence: true)

   private
      def create_remember_token
        self.remember_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    end
end
```

**Attendance Model:**

```
class Attendance < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :code, :email
  belongs_to :user
  validates_presence_of :user
end
```

So far I'm only trying to enforce the association between User and Attendance, once I get that working I'll do the same to Events. Also, this is Rails 3.2.19 and Ruby 1.9.3.

EDIT: Here is the code I'm using for the form, I believe that it works because until I put the validation into the model it was creating rows into the Attendance table.

```
<% provide(:title, 'Test Event') %>
<h1>Attendance Registration</h1>

<div class="row">
    <div class="span6 offset3">
      <%= form_for(@attendance) do |f| %>
        <%= render 'shared/attendance_error_messages' %>

        <%= f.label :email %>
        <%= f.text_field :email %>

        <%= f.label :code %>
        <%= f.text_field :code %>

        <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also, here's the attendance controller, if that helps.

```
class AttendancesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @attendance = Attendance.new
  end

  def create
    @attendance = Attendance.new(params[:attendance])
    if @attendance.save
      flash[:success] = "Attendance logged."
        redirect_to root_path
    else
        render 'new'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you please tell me more on when you get this error?

Comment: I made a page to allow someone to enter an email and a code to create a new row into the attendance table specified. However, when doing so I get an flash error saying "* User can't be blank".
Also, I know that this page works at creating a new attendance row, as until I put in the validation in he attendance model it was correctly creating the row.

Comment: in User model you have defined has_may relationship with inverse_of, Try to specify inverse_of in attendance model also, belongs_to :user, :inverse_of :attendence

Comment: Unfortunately it still seems to be having the same problem, stating that User cannot be blank.

Comment: Paste the code of your form

Comment: Where do you set the user for the attendance you are creating?

Comment: I already have a table of users set that I'm trying to associate with. When I create a new attendance with the form, I put in an email that should be able to associate to the email of a user.

Comment: So users are not yet logged in when presented the 'new attendance' form? Looks you are trying to solve two different problems here... logging in users, and associating attendances to users.

Comment: The user is already logged in when doing so, but still having the error.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your form to avoid the user presence error

```
<%= f.hidden_field :user_id, current_user.id %>
```

Comment: After adding in that line, it still seems to be having the same problem that the User is blank.

Comment: @RSB, that kind of an approach works but it has its loopholes. Check out my response.